# How to capture redirect URL in Swift (after auth step of OAuth2)

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am new to Swift. I need help in capturing the redirect URL after a user authorizes my application to use their account. The redirect URL contains the auth_code that I would exchange for a token.

I am spinning in circles trying to use NSURLSessionDataDelegate:

```
class MySessionDelegate: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
    func URLSession(_: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
        println(newRequest)
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

but it is not being called in:

```
var authUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=\(responseType)" +
            "&client_id=\(apiKey)" +
            "&state=\(randomState)" +
            "&redirect_uri=\(redirectUrl)")

var session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: MySessionDelegate(), delegateQueue: nil)
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: authUrl!)

myWebView.loadRequest(request)
```

I then added a NSURLProtocol to print the requests (I can see the redirect URL in the console), but this applies to all requests in the session which is not optimal:

```
var requestCount = 0

class urlProtocol: NSURLProtocol {
override class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
    println("Request #\(requestCount++): URL = \(request.URL.absoluteString)")
    return false
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would work outside of a UIWebView, if you were actually running the task on your URLSession.  With a UIWebView you aren't using (at least directly) the URLSession API.  Like you said with NSURLProtocol, you'll capture every request that goes across the wire.

UIWebView has a delegate you might be able to use.  You'll have to make sure you're viewController is the delegate for UIWebView then implement this method from the UIWebViewDelegate protocol.

```
optional func webView(webView: UIWebView,
                      shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest,
                      navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool

{
    return true
}
```

The request will have the url in it, but the navigation type will have `UIWebViewNavigation.Other`.  You can decide to return true or false depending on if you want the webView to actually load the request.  In a typical redirect scenario, you'll see the first request which you created with `myWebView.loadRequest(request)`.  You may see other requests if the user is clicking links, or interacting with the page, but their navigation type will not be `UIWebViewNavigationType.Other`, but rather something like `.LinkClicked` or `.FormSubmitted`.